# The name property of a Timeline-placed object cannot be modified

Tags: flash, flash-cc

I'm having this error in [flash](/questions/tagged/flash)

```
Error: Error #2078: The name property of a Timeline-placed object cannot be modified.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/set name()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
```

My code is the following:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

name.label = "Please, enter your name...";

enter.label = "Enter";

enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitName);

function submitName(pEvent: MouseEvent): void {
    var myVariable = name.text;
    output.text = "Thanks for your help, " + myVariable;
}
```

The program should take a name in a textbox and return it in a dynamic text instance when a button is pressed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: Sorry about that. I made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `name` as a name of any object ( component, variable, ... ) because it refers to the name of your MainTimeline ( `root` ).

So to avoid that error, you have to change the name of the component that you've inserted to the stage.

Don't forget also to avoid using [keywords and reserved words](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f6e) reserved for use by ActionScript.

Hope that can help.